# Selecting a database in mysql with spaces in its name

Tags: mysql, database, console, spaces

I want to select my particular database in mysql console, but the problem is that my database name has a space in between and mysql ignores the part after the space. For instance, when i give the command:

```
use 'student registration'
```

I get the message:

```
cannot find database 'student'
```

Comment: It works for me, no matter if I use ' or `. Difference between versions, maybe? (mine is 5.0 on Windows).

Comment: My hats off to the dba who manged this. As if writing good sql in itself was not challenging enough. Sigh!

Answer (score 38):

You should try using back ticks ("`") to quote your database name.  Generally speaking, it's probably better to use a naming convention to eliminate white space, e.g.

```
USE `StudentRegistration`;
```

or

```
USE `student_registration`;
```

Comment: Even with spaces, it's better to use these back ticks. Nice answer David. +1

Answer (score 13):

You have two options.

1  Enclose the database name in backticks or single quotes.

> ```
> USE `student registration`;
> USE 'student registration';
> ```

2  Escape the white space character.

> `USE student\ registration;`

Oddly enough this produces.

> ERROR:  Unknown command '\ '.

But still changes the database.

Answer (score 2):

When I had to deal with other people's tables with spaces the following worked:

```
use `student registration`;
```

At least that would be yours.

Answer (score 2):

Use Double quotes instead of single, double quotes worked for me :

```
USE "student registration";
```

Comment: Hi I used all techniques here such as "order details" [order details] and 'order details' but they all didnlt work do you have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `student registration` without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

USE `student registration`; - This worked for me like a gem... Also tried other alternatives provided here... But nothing worked for me in MySQL;

Answer (score -1):

You have to use square brackets to get this work:

```
Use [student registration]
```