# Remove white space from table_name in MySql?

Tags: mysql

Ex:
Server SQL mode. If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, you can quote identifiers withdouble quotes (although backticks still are permitted).

```
CREATE TABLE "my table" ("my-int-column" INT);
```

I have tried the drop, and described like this:

```
describe 'my table';
drop table 'my table';

describe my table;
drop table my table;
```

Syntax error.

Comment: You mentioned *"backticks still are permitted"* - have you tried using those instead of `'`? And did it work? Or perhaps the suggestions here: [Selecting a database in mysql with spaces in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506826/selecting-a-database-in-mysql-with-spaces-in-its-name)

Comment: I have tried it. It doesn't work. but thank you for taking the time.