# query with space in name

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a database that is allready setup and can not be changed due to ERP software running on it. When trying to connect to retrieve some data into a table in PHP, i get the following error:

> [SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Lareco Live'

I understand that this is due to the space in the tablename --> `[Lareco Live$Lead]`

This is my script:

```
// Establishes the connection
$dbh = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if ($dbh === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

$sql = "select No_, Description from [Lareco Live$Lead] with (nolock) "; 
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($dbh, $sql);
if ($getResults === false) { 
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried quoting the name: `['Lareco Live$Lead']`. Also pay attention with the `$` in the name as with double quotes PHP will interpret `$Lead` as a variable.

Comment: Maybe you should add quote to the table name like this "table name" or 'table name' or `table name`. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506826/selecting-a-database-in-mysql-with-spaces-in-its-name

Comment: just escape $Lead: \$Lead --> $sql = "select No_, Description from [Lareco Live\$Lead] with (nolock) ";

Comment: Adding to the comment by @lptr, the problem is not the space in the name but the `$` character that needs to be escaped in php. I suggest you use names that conform to [regular identifier naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) to avoid the need to escape special characters in code and enclose the names is square brackets or double-quotes.

Comment: Honestly, I'd consider chnaging the name of your table, `Lareco Live$Lead` is a *really* poor choice for an object name.  `LarecoLiveLead` or `Lareco_Live_Lead` would be much better choices, as neither need to be delimit identified.

Comment: comment from lptr was correct, escaping solved the issue! thank you so much!